# Python website convert into Adobe Dreamweaver CS3

Tags: python, dreamweaver

I am comfortable in Adobe Dreamweaver CS3. Is there a way to convert a website written in the Python language into Dreamweaver for those who aren't familiar with writing in code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that any functionality needs to remain intact… no.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a tool which can convert a python site into dreamweaver, not possible yet, such intelligent machines are not yet invented, but evolution has produced you,
so what you can do is see the site page by page, and make it again in dreamweaver. If you have specs and designs of python site handy that would speed up the things. offcourse you can easily copy css etc, you can use tools like firbug/chrome inspector to see how css is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply copy the HTML that Python generates to make a static copy of the website, but you'll lose any interactivity. In other words, you won't be able to use the website's administrative panel to modify anything. It will let you modify the style of the website, however.